# Docker crashed after Windows update

Tags: docker

I have a problem with docker:
After a windows update docker gives me the following error:

```
Unable to create: Der ausgeführte Befehl wurde beendet, da die Einstellungsvariable "ErrorActionPreference" oder ein allgemeiner Parameter auf "Stop" festgelegt ist: Das Objekt ist bereits vorhanden.
.
   bei Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:Zeile 36.
   bei Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:Zeile 77.
   bei Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Start>b__0() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:Zeile 61.
   bei Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:Zeile 59.
```

The only way to adress this issue seems to be a hard reset of docker, which I did. This resulted in a loop. Anytime I click on: "Reset to factory defaults" I takes seconds until I recieve the same Error message again.

This stays true for deinstalling docker and reinstalling it again. 
I cleaned the registry, deinstalled windowsupdates (only 3 out 4 were deinstallable).

[image: Docker Error Picture]

Does anyone has other ideas to try?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

The problem can be solved by deinstalling docker, deinstalling all Hyper V driver in the device manager of windows and reinstalling docker again.